# "Java EE module dependencies" options missing in Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse-3.6

I've just downloaded the eclipse helios IDE. I'm trying to create a dynamic web project. In eclipse galileo we had a option called "Java EE module dependencies" to add the dependency jars and other projects to the classpath on the server.

But this option is missing in helios, I've downloaded [link text](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/SR1/eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-win32.zip) eclipse Java EE version of eclipse.

How should I add the referenced libraries to the classpath?

Answer (score 8):

The preferences option called "Java EE module dependencies" is removed from eclipse helios and a new option called "Web Deployment Assembly" is added. Please see [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-java-ee-module-dependencies-is-replaced-by-web-deployment-assembly/).

To add new jar references you can click on "Add' --> "Java Build Path Entries", then select the required jars then click on finish